# Implementing often-occuring determinism patterns in Prolog

Tags: coding-style, prolog, deterministic

When programming in Prolog I often write predicates whose behavior should be semi-deterministic when called with all arguments instantiated (and whose behavior should be non-deterministic otherwise).

A concrete use case for this is my predicate `walk/3`, which implements graph walks. Since multiple paths can exist between two vertices, the instantiation `(+,+)` gives multiple choicepoints after `true`. These are, however, quite useless. Calling code must explicitly use `once/1` for performance reasons.

```
%! walk(+Graph:ugraph, +StartVertex, +EndVertex) is semidet.
%! walk(+Graph:ugraph, -StartVertex, +EndVertex) is nondet.
%! walk(+Graph:ugraph, +StartVertex, -EndVertex) is nondet.
%! walk(+Graph:ugraph, -StartVertex, -EndVertex) is nondet.
```

Semi-determinism can be forced by the use of `once/1` in the calling context, but I want to implement semi-determinism as a property of the predicate `walk/3`, and not as something that has to be treated specially every time it is called.

In addition to concerns over code aesthetics, the calling context need not always know whether its call to `walk/3` is semi-deterministic or not. For example:

```
%! cycle(+Graph:ugraph, +Vertex) is semidet.
%! cycle(+Graph:ugraph, -Vertex) is nondet.

cycle(Graph, Vertex):-
  walk(Graph, Vertex, Vertex).
```

I have come up with the following solution, which does produce the correct behavior.

```
walk_wrapper(Graph, Start, End):-
  call_ground_as_semidet(walk(Graph, Start, End)).

:- meta_predicate(call_ground_as_semidet(0)).
call_ground_as_semidet(Goal):-
  ground(Goal), !,
  Goal, !.
call_ground_as_semidet(Goal):-
  Goal.
```

However, this solution has deficiencies:

- It's not **generic** enough, e.g. sometimes `ground` should be `nonvar`.
- It is not **stylistic**, requiring an extra predicate wrapper every time it is used.
- It may also be slightly **inefficient**.

My question is: are there other ways in which often-occurring patterns of (non-)determinism, like the one described here, can be generically/efficiently/stylistically programmed in Prolog?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question, with a simpler example: you want a predicate that will behave as `memberchk/2` when the first argument is ground and as `member/2` when the first argument is not ground?

Comment: Did you already checked [mavis](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=mavis) pack ?

Comment: @Boris Indeed, that is a much simpler example. I'll update my post accordingly.

Comment: Can you give at least some context to the question? In other words, a situation in which you need to use a predicate like that? I have trouble imagining what the use case is, exactly...

Comment: @Boris I've update the post with a use case.

Comment: @CapelliC Mavis is a nifty library indeed. However, it targets argument types, not predicate modes.

Comment: extending mavis should be feasible and efficient - sorry I have no time at all, but maybe Michael Hendricks could help ?

Comment: @Boris: library(xpath) it's a good candidate for an applicative context where efficiency and control make a difference

Comment: Neither `memberchk/2` nor `member/2` are ISO. But at least, [`member/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member) is part of the Prolog prologue.

Comment: @false: I don't get the motivation to exclude memberchk/2 - ok, it's a single call, but could be handy to have ready in practical case, like ?- maplist(memberchk(X), L_of_X)

Comment: @CapelliC: memberchk/2 has no declarative meaning: `memberchk(a,Xs),Xs=[b,a].` fails but `memberchk(a,Xs),Xs=[b,a].` succeeds.

Comment: most (all?) Prolog code with a cut has peculiar reading. But quite useful, or even *necessary*. What's the *real* problem about `memberchk(X, L) :- member(X, L), !.`

Comment: @false I've removed mention of `member/2` and `memberchk/2`, since that may have been confusing. (Also, I was wrong about the ISO status of the predicates, so thanks for pointing that out!)

Comment: @false: I suppose you mean `memberchk(a,Xs),Xs=[b,a].` vs. `Xs=[b,a], memberchk(a,Xs).`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should experiment with **double negation as failure**. Yes a ground goal can only be true or false, so it should not leave any choice points. Lets assume we have an acyclic graph, to make matters simple:

[image]

If I use this code:

```
edge(a, b).         edge(a, c).
edge(a, d).         edge(b, c).
edge(c, d).         edge(c, e).
edge(d, e).

path(X,X).
path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), path(Z,Y).
```

The Prolog system will now leave choice points for closed queries:

```
?- path(a, e).
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
false.
```

In my opinion the recommended approach, to eliminate these 
choice points and nevertheless have a multi-moded predicate,
is to use so called meta-programming in Prolog.

meta-programming is also sometimes derogeratively called
non-logical programming, since it is based on non-logical
predicates such as ground/1, !/0 or (+)/1. But lets call 
it meta-programming when declarativity is not impacted.

You could write a wrapper smart/1 as follows, doing the 
same as your call_ground_as_semidet/1, but with a small nuance:

```
smart(G) :- ground(G), !, \+ \+ G.
smart(G) :- G.
```

The Prolog system will not anymore leave a choice point for closed queries:

```
?- smart(path(a,e)).
true.
```

The advantage of \+ \+ over once, is that the former does
not only leave no choice points, but also removes the trail. It 
is sometimes called the **garbage collection meta-predicate** of Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer** but too long for a comment. Keep in mind I am not sure I understand exactly, so I want to re-state your question first.

To take your graph example. You want to be able to ask the following questions using the same call of the same predicate.

Given a graph,

*Question 1*: is vertex B reachable from vertex A (somehow)? - **yes or no**

*Question 2*: which vertices are reachable from A? - **enumerate by backtracking**

*Question 3*: from which vertices is B reachable? - **enumerate by backtracking**

*Question 4*: which A and B exist for which B is reachable from A? - **enumerate by backtracking**

And I might be wrong here, but it seems that answering Question 1 and Question 2 might employ a different search strategy than answering Question 3?

More generally, you want to have a way of saying: if I have a yes-or-no question, succeed or fail. Otherwise, enumerate answers.

Here comes my trouble: what are you going to do with the two different *types* of answers? And what are the situations in which you don't know in advance which type of answer you need? (If you do know in advance, you can use `once(goal)`, as you said yourself.)

PS:
There is obviously `setof/3`, which will fail if there are no answers, or collect all answers. Are there situations in which you want to know *some* of the answers but you don't want to collect all of them? Is this an efficiency concern because of the size and number of the answers?

Comment: @Boris Your reformulation of my question is correct. In the specific example I gave, Q2 and Q3 happen to use the same search strategy. The two main reasons for wanting to enforce semi-determinism are indeed performance and doing away with superfluous choicepoints. The calling context can indeed use `once/1` or `setof/3`, but I am inquiring into whether there are solutions that can be applied to the goal itself, not to (all) its calling contexts?

Comment: enumeration make easy program **lazy** Prolog. I like a lot - most pleasant Prolog code is based on proper expression of laziness. Being able to be efficient, is important.

Comment: @WouterBeek I get it maybe. Excuse the circular reasoning, but if the calling context does not know which question is being asked, how do you know what to do with the answer? In other words, at some point up the chain of callers you must know if it's a semi-deterministic or non-deterministic call, right? (not really sure....)

Comment: @Boris As an example of a calling context that does not know in advance which question is being asked, I can define a *cycle* as a closed walk: `cycle(G, V):- walk(G, V, V)`. Cycle has modes `(+,+) semidet` and `(+,-) nondet`.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer** but an advice. 
Maybe I missunderstood your question. I think you are trying to address performance issues by forcing a predicate to be non-deterministic. That question is pointless: if `p(X)` is non-deterministic (multiple solutions), then `p(X),!` is deterministic (first solution only).

You should not address performance issues by altering program logic or predicate reversibility. I suggest a different approach:

First, take advantage of prolog indexing. For example:

```
cycle(+Graph:ugraph, +Vertex)
```

is NOT the same (in terms of performance) as:

```
cycle(+Vertex, +Graph:ugraph)
```

You should find documentation on prolog indexing (and performance impact) on the Web.

Second, write multiple implementations for the same problem. Each one will optimize performance for a different case. Then, write a predicate that chooses the best implementation for each case.